# How can I define the output directory a bundled .NET Core SingleFile published app will be deployed to?

Tags: systemd, services, systemd-unit, .net

I am deploying a .NET Core Worker Service app in linux, as a systemd daemon/service, as recommended. The .NET Core app is published using the SingleFile property, which generates an all-in-one exe file. In the systemd/system/myService.service file, I set ExecStart to point to the path of this exe file.

It works, but I notice that at every system boot, the service working directory where the exe bundle is "extracted" mounts to /var/tmp/.net/root/{dynamic directory} - a dynamic directory generated at every boot.

I need the files to be mounted to a fixed directory.
I could not find the option to control this in the .service configuration options.

Anyone knows how to accomplish that ?

Comment: Given that the extraction is something the app does, not systemd, you should rather be looking in .net documentation. I have zero experience with .net, but [what I googled](https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/main/accepted/2020/single-file/extract.md#extraction-location) unfortunately does not suggest configurability here.

Comment: I am afraid you are right, at least it makes sense, I thought of that. In googling configuring this setting in .net core, I only found some references to an environment flag named `DOTNET_BUNDLE_EXTRACT_BASE_DIR`, but had no luck in seeing this fix my problem.

Comment: @MichałPolitowski: oh, only now I opened your *what I googled* link (following ReedGhost's answer below). You found material I did not, thanks for that! You should have made an answer out of that to get your upvote...

Comment: Well, from that document I understood that the variable is only responsible for the `/var/tmp/.net/root/` part, so probably not helpful. If I misunderstood or if the document is wrong and it helps then great.

Comment: I saw that the installation goes on /var/temp/.net/root/{dynamic string} generated every time the service is started again (or machine booted, in my case) So it helps me.

Answer (score 3):

In your use case, using the [information provided by Michal Politowski](https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/main/accepted/2020/single-file/extract.md#extraction-location) in the comments. The reason your extraction directory is set to /var/tmp is because

```
   DOTNET_BUNDLE_EXTRACT_BASE_DIR
```

does not exist within the environment for your service.

Since this is the case, [you should define that environment variable persistently](https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/administration-linux/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-linux/) on the user you are running your systemd service as.

(Or [define an environment file or Environment=](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/using-environment-variables-in-systemd-units.html) option in the service file itself)