# Why is this install command returning 1?

Tags: dpkg, debian-installer

I am drowning, would any one of us be so kind to throw me a lifesaver... in time :)

I am adventuring myself in deployment a .NET Core Worker Service app in Linux. Am trying to create a package for that.

[This article](https://medium.com/bluekiri/packaging-a-net-core-service-for-ubuntu-4f8e9202d1e5) seems to tackle exactly what I want to achieve.
Have followed it, but my `dpkg-buildpackage -b --no-sign` is failing, as far as I can tell in the install statement below:
`install -D -m 755 bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/linux-x64/publish/* /opt/myApp` (the install statement is part of my `rules` file created after running `dh_make` as instructed in the article)

My `rules` files:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
# See debhelper(7) (uncomment to enable)
# output every command that modifies files on the build system.
#export DH_VERBOSE = 1


# see FEATURE AREAS in dpkg-buildflags(1)
#export DEB_BUILD_MAINT_OPTIONS = hardening=+all

# see ENVIRONMENT in dpkg-buildflags(1)
# package maintainers to append CFLAGS
#export DEB_CFLAGS_MAINT_APPEND  = -Wall -pedantic
# package maintainers to append LDFLAGS
#export DEB_LDFLAGS_MAINT_APPEND = -Wl,--as-needed


%:
    dh $@ --with=systemd

override_dh_auto_build:
    dotnet publish -r linux-x64 --self-contained true -p:PublishTrimmed=true

override_dh_auto_install:
    # install application
    mkdir -p /home/myUserName/myApp
    echo 'Log Message 1'
    install -D -m 755 bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/linux-x64/publish/* /home/myUserName/myApp
    echo 'Log Message 2'
    rm /home/myUserName/myApp/*.pdb #delete pdb

    # install debug symbols
    mkdir -p /home/myUserName/debug/myApp
    install -D -m 644 bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/linux-x64/publish/*.pdb /home/myUserName/debug/myApp
    dotnet-symbol --symbols bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/linux-x64/publish/ -o  /home/myUserName/debug/myApp
    # auto-install disabled

override_dh_shlibdeps:
    # shilbdeps disabled

override_dh_strip:
    # strip disabled

# dh_make generated override targets
# This is example for Cmake (See https://bugs.debian.org/641051 )
#override_dh_auto_configure:
#   dh_auto_configure -- #  -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=$(DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH)
```

If I run it separately, adding the verbose flag (-v), I do not see any error messages (tried `| grep -i error`, nothing).
I am a beginner in Linux, I learned that echoing `$?` gives me the last statement exit code (for that matter, running an ls and echoing $? returns 0, running the install statement above and echoing $? returns 1).

Running `errno 1` gives `EPERM 1 Operation not permitted`

I thought perhaps the problem is in writing to /opt. Changed the destination folder to something within /home, still get the same results.

How do I proceed from here ? How can I know what is going wrong with this install statement ? Somewhere I read that the package must be installed. I run `dpkg-deb -I myApp`, but it returns `error: failed to read archive 'myApp': No such file or directory`, which I believe indicates the package is not installed.

Please be so kind and save a life !

Comment: [Please](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1285628/why-is-this-install-command-returning-1) don't [cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/717014).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When building a package, instead of installing files to their final locations, you need to install them to a “marshaling” area. In Debian packages that’s in a directory with the same name as your binary package, inside `debian`:

```
install -D -m 755 bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/linux-x64/publish/* debian/netcoreapp/opt/myApp
```

(assuming your package is `netcoreapp`), but this doesn’t explain the issues you’re having with `install`, and probably won’t fix them.

Instead of figuring this out manually, **you should use `dh_install`** instead of `install`:

```
dh_install bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/linux-x64/publish/* opt/myApp
```

Comment: I hope this debian marshaling directory thing is not written somewhere out there in capital letters, so my despair is justifiable. Thanks a lot for this piece of information! I purposely ripped off all "debian" occurrences in the rules file thinking "why do I need this in the destination folder ?" Will try this out

Comment: I don't understand, however, how what you say makes sense - since the install destination folder in the rules file is the folder that was just created in the preceding mkdir step ? I mean, it looks like just a regular folder ?

Comment: Thank you for the hint of running `dh_install` to digure out what is going on. I understand it does not accept any of the install options, such as m, v, D... ?

Comment: The destination directory is mentioned *e.g.* in slide 22 of [the packaging tutorial](https://www.debian.org/doc/devel-manuals#packaging-tutorial). I can’t remember where I learned about it, it’s been a long time... I’m not sure why your `install` fails but I do know that packages aren’t supposed to touch anything outside their source tree or `/tmp` or `/var/tmp` ([Policy section 4.9](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-source.html#main-building-script-debian-rules)). `dh_install` doesn’t have the same options as `install`, see its manpage for details.

Comment: I changed the rules file `mkdir` statement to `debian/netcoreapp/opt/myApp` and all the subsequent references to this folder to this string. But I still get the same error. Running dh_install apparently returns no error, removing the options (v,D,etc) (even if I leave /opt/myApp' as the destination directory.

Comment: Sorry to be mixing topics but your last comment references [another issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/615635/433212) I have in this deployment saga. Do you recall anything on those docs referring to controlling the "source tree" directory ?

Comment: `dh_install` takes its destination as a subdirectory of `debian/package`, and handles permissions etc. for you; that’s why even `/opt/myApp` works.

Comment: using the debian folder as the destination marshal directory as you recommended **AND** replacing install with dh_install finally creates the package. Would you edit the answer just to stress that one using install is not always predictable, while using dh_install the package should be created without problems, so I can mark it as the answer ?

Comment: I’ve updated the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, assuming your package is called myApp:

```
override_dh_auto_install:
    # install application
    mkdir -p debian/myApp/opt/myApp
    install -D -m 755 bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/linux-x64/publish/* debian/myApp/opt/myApp/myApp
    rm debian/myApp/opt/myApp/*.pdb #delete pdb

    # install debug symbols
    mkdir -p debian/myApp-dbg/opt/myApp
    install -D -m 644 bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/linux-x64/publish/*.pdb debian/myApp-dbg/opt/myApp
    dotnet-symbol --symbols bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/linux-x64/publish/ -o  debian/myApp-dbg/opt/myApp
    # auto-install disabled
```

The `dpkg-buildpackage -b --no-sign` command does not install anything. It just create the deb package. Afterwards, you can install it with `dpkg -i yourpackagename.deb`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for giving a hand. If I understand what you suggest - creating and using the debian destination folder that was created after running `dh_make` - I have just changed my rules file replacing all occurrences of `/home/myUserName/myApp` to `debian/netcoreapp/opt/myApp` (also suggested by Stephen Kitt above) but the install still fails with the same message. I mean, `dpkg-buildpackage` still fails with the same message.

Comment: It's better to use `dh_install`as @Stephen Kitt suggested. You can't use whatever you want as the install folder.

Comment: that's what I just commented out below his answer now - using the debian marshall directory **AND** switching to dh_install finally creates the package.